# How to make a drawing action run in an left released event in Game Maker?

Tags: game-maker, events

At first I tried to make the progress bar update using only one object that would command everything (`obj_Control`), linking to the `global left released` event a script containing the `draw_rectangle` function, but I got no results.

The Game Maker did not acknowledge any errors, but the progress bar did not update when I clicked on the created rectangles.

**obj_Control** (already without the `draw_rectangle` event):

[image]

Because of this I decided to create 3 new objects (`obj_Vida, obj_Fome, obj_Energia`), each containing a sprite and when each was clicked it would perform the action to update the progress bar:

[image]

**obj_Vida**:

scpt 1 => `obj_Control.vida+=10;` (**applies to self**)

scpt 2 => `draw_healthbar(120,100,240,120,vida,c_black,c_red,c_green,0,true,true);` (**applies to obj_Control**)

**obj_Fome**:

script 1 => `obj_Control.fome+=10;` (**applies to self**)

script 2 => `draw_healthbar(120,150,240,170,fome,c_black,c_red,c_green,0,true,true);` (**applies to obj_Control**)

**obj_Energia**:

script 1 => `obj_Control.energia+=10;` (**applies to self**)

script 2 => `draw_healthbar(120,200,240,220,energia,c_black,c_red,c_green,0,true,true);` (**applies to obj_Control**)

**Room**:

[image]

Room size => 360x640

Translate => **vida/life, fome/hungry, energia/energy**

What happens is that even dying of clicking on objects (`obj_Vida, obj_Fome, obj_Energia`) nothing happens to the progress bar. I discovered that it is because of the event, it would have to be a draw event. I added one below the `left released` event, but it did not work.

I apologize for any typing errors. I am not an English speaker and I had to translate everything. If something was not clear, please signal.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`draw_` functions works only in `Draw` event (to be precise, it works anywhere, but all what you drew will be erased before `Draw` event). See [Draw Event](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/000_using%20gamemaker/events/draw%20event.html) in the documentation.

So, you need separate it like this:

**obj_Vida**, Left Mouse Button Pressed event:

```
obj_Control.vida+=10;
```

**obj_Fome**, Left Mouse Button Pressed event:

```
obj_Control.fome+=10;
```

**obj_Energia**, Left Mouse Button Pressed event:

```
obj_Control.energia+=10;
```

**obj_control**, Draw event:

```
draw_healthbar(120,100,240,120,vida,c_black,c_red,c_green,0,true,true);
draw_healthbar(120,150,240,170,fome,c_black,c_red,c_green,0,true,true);
draw_healthbar(120,200,240,220,energia,c_black,c_red,c_green,0,true,true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but with me only worked after I preferred to use `draw_sprite` instead of `draw_healthbar`. I deleted the 3 objects and I preferred to draw the sprites by the own `obj_Control` plus the global event left released